# How can i download a specific track from iTunes store xcode

Tags: ios, itunes, xcode4.5

I have to download a specific track from iTunes Music store on Button Click from my app. I am not able to find exactly how this can be performed.

I have implemented the following code to fetch the play list and songs in the playlist:

```
-(void)musicPlaylist{

    playlistQuery= [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    NSArray *arr = [playlistQuery collections];
    NSLog(@"Playlist is : %@",arr);
    int count1=[arr count];
    NSLog(@" count 1 is %d",count1);

    for (MPMediaPlaylist *playlist in arr) {
      NSLog (@"%@", [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName]);
      playlistTitle = [playlist valueForProperty: MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName];
      playlistDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:playlistTitle,@"playlist Title",nil];
      [dictArray addObject:playlistDict];

      NSArray *songs = [playlist items];
      for (MPMediaItem *song in songs) {
        NSString *songTitle =[song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songArray addObject:songTitle];
      }
      NSLog(@"Playlist is %@",playlistTitle);
      NSLog(@"Playlist Songs are %@",songArray);
    }
}
```

Now I want to allow the app to download a specific track on button click. How can I do that?

Comment: I have implemented the following code to fetch the play list and songs in the playlist

Comment: What is the connection between the code and your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is the ID of the track in the iTunes store. 
Then follow this tutorial to present the store UI in your app:

[Making Store Purchases with the SKStoreProductViewController Class](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class)

This library allows you to search in the iTunes Store (in order to get the ID): https://github.com/gangverk/iTunesSearch